# Linux Virtual Machine Network Connection issues

Tags: networking, internet, virtualization

I am running an Oracle VM for Linux and want to update ubuntu from 19.04-19.10 .

On the VM, I can use the internet fine through firefox, but when I attempt to use the software update tool or any variation of "get apt" in the terminal I am told there is no network connection.

Has anyone else ran into this issue and found a solution?

Comment: 19.10 is past End Of Life, and upgrading to it is no longer supported here. Consider a clean install of 20.04, which is supported for five years,

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is EOL (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/) so Ubuntu 19.10 is now off-topic on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.